# How to place std::mutex inside std::tuple with some other classes?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'd like to have `std::shared_ptr<std::tuple<MyClass, std::mutex>>`.

`std::mutex` is neither copyable nor movable. How to initialize it?

Comment: Can you just use a pair instead? Pair has a constructor that forwards arguments to each type separately. Another common solution is to work with a unique pointer to a mutex.

Comment: I'm not sure but I don't think you should have a problem with `std::make_shared<std::tuple<MyClass, std::mutex>>()` if `MyClass` is default constructible.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x, it's not default constructible.

Comment: Do you need exception safety during construction?  Ie, can `MyClass::MyClass` throw?

Comment: @Yakk, no, it doesn't throw.

Comment: Can you construct a `std::tuple<MyClass, std::mutex>`?  Without any `shared_ptr` being involved?  Does it need to ba `tuple<MyClass, std::mutex>`, would a `tuple<MyClass&, std::mutex&>` be good enough so long as it also manages lifetime? (it would have 2 pointers of overhead)

Comment: @Yakk, it's possible only with the default constructor of MyClass.

Comment: @Velkan So your problem is `std::tuple` not `std::shared_ptr` then.  Got it.  How portable do we need to be?  :)

Comment: @Yakk, I'm not caring actually any more after the first comment with `std::pair`. So, the discussion becomes purely academic (and you can choose the level of portability).

Answer (score 1):

The easy solution for two arguments is `std::pair` and `std::piecewise_construct`.

`std::tuple` is missing that.  I consider that a flaw.

If we want `tuple` (say more than 2 arguments), we can do it with some horrible code, for limited values of "can do it".

```
template<class T>
struct placement_shared_helper {
  std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T),alignof(T)> data;
  T* get() { return reinterpret_cast<T*>(&data); }
  template<class F>
  void construct( F&& f ) {
    std::forward<F>(f)((void*)&data);
  }
  // dangerous if construct throws:
  ~placement_shared_helper(){ get()->~T(); }
};

template<class T, class F>
std::shared_ptr<T> make_placement_shared( F&& f ) {
  auto r1 = std::make_shared<placement_shared_helper<T>>();
  r1->construct( std::forward<F>(f) );
  return {r1->get(), r1}; // aliasing constructor
}
```

this requires you pass in a function object that, when passed a `void*` of sufficient size and alignment, will construct your type in the pointed to storage.

You can improve the exception safety of `placement_shared_helper`, but it is work and I'm lazy.  Consider catching any exceptions from construct and `std::terminate`.

For the next part, we cheat.  This violates the standard, as we take uninitialized memory and interpret it as a tuple to get the offsets the tuple stores its objects in.  Bad programmer.

```
template<class Dest, std::size_t...Is, class...Args>
void placement_construct( std::index_sequence<Is...>, Dest* here, std::tuple<Args...> args ) {
  new((void*)here) Dest( std::get<Is>(args)... );
}
template<class Dest, class...Args>
void placement_construct( Dest* here, std::tuple<Args...> args ) {
  return placement_construct( std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{}, here, std::move(args) );
}

template<class Dest, std::size_t...Is, class...Tuples>
void placement_construct_tuple( std::index_sequence<Is...>, void* here, Tuples... tuples ) {
  using discard=int[];
  (void)discard{0,(void(
      placement_construct( &std::get<Is>(*(Dest*)here), std::move(tuples) )
  ),0)...};
}

template<class Dest, class...Tuples>
void placement_construct_tuple( void* here, Tuples... tuples ) {
  placement_construct_tuple<Dest>( std::index_sequence_for<Tuples...>{}, here, std::move(tuples)... );
}
```

this presumes that a tuple is just a bunch of constructed objects at particular locations.  We take our tuple-shaped block of memory and construct each of its elements in turn.  If an exception is thrown bad things happen; you probably want to try catch terminate.

`make_placement_shared` takes a function that takes a `void*` and constructs your object.

`placement_construct_tuple` takes a set of tuples, and uses them to construct the objects each in turn in the tuple.

```
auto r = make_placement_shared<std::tuple<MyClass, std::mutex>>(
  [&](void* here) {
    placement_construct_tuple<std::tuple<MyClass, std::mutex>>(here,
      std::forward_as_tuple( args_to_construct_MyClass_go_here ),
      std::make_tuple() // no args for mutex
    );
  }
);
```

and barring typos and the undefined behavior, finished.

Comment: Would you use this code if your life depended on it?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin No, I would not install uncompiled template metaprogramming code into a heart rate monitor then install it in my chest?  That would be stupid.  I'd also probably make a `std::tuple<optional<MyClass>, std::mutex>` and eat the bytes for the engaged bool rather than try the above.  In the medium term, I suspect a `piecewise_convert` ctor for tuple may show up and do away with the above hack.